# Is using Task Gate with x86 IDT, the only way to handle kernel mode ( ring 0) stack fault exception?

Tags: exception, kernel

Assume that kernel always executes in Ring 0 privilege level. For the stack fault exception (due to stack overflow or limit violations), which gate should be used for x86 IDT ( Interrupt descriptor table) setup out of Trap Gate, Interrupt Gate and Task Gate?

X86 processor needs stack to push eflags, CS, eip on stack before calling stack fault exception handler. Which means there is a need of Stack switch to call exception handler.

Is using Task Gate the only way to perform Stack Switch?

Is using Task Gate the only way to write stack fault handler for kernel stack faults?

**Intel Manual writes-**
"A new tss permits the handler to use a new privilege level 0 stack when handling the exception or interrupt. If an exception or interrupt occurs when the current privilege level 0 stack is corrupted, accessing the handler through a task gate can prevent a system crash by providing the handler with a new privilege level 0 stack".

Thanks in advance for your response.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, yes. Imagine how it works:

1. You overflow your stack.
2. The GPF handler gets called, however it can't do anything because the R0 stack is corrupted.
3. The process tries to call the Double Fault handler, but can't.
4. The process triple faults.

If you have a TSS, the following gets done:

1. You overflow your stack.
2. The processor tries to call the GPF handler, resulting in a taskswitch
3. The processor switches tasks, resulting in new stack.
4. Everything continues as normal.